# Aggregation of BitSet collection data in Scala

Tags: scala, scala-collections, bitset

I have a function `f` that returns a BitSet from two input parameters.
Given values list, I need to return a joined BitSet from the function `f`.
For example, with a values List that has 3 elements `List(10,20,30)`, the method should return as follows:

```
val l = List(100,200,300)
def shiftAndJoin(values:List[Int]) = {
  f(10, l(0)) ++
  f(20, l(1)) ++
  f(30, l(2))
}
```

The simple and intuitive solution might be iteration over values  with index to aggregate the BitSet() collection variable like this. However, I guess there should be a better way than this (some way that does not use ++= operator).

```
var r = BitSet()
(values zipWithIndex).foreach { case (v, i) => 
   r ++= f(v, l(i)) 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, this one-liner should do it:

```
values.zip(l).map{case (v, i) => f(v,i)}.reduce{ _ ++ _ }
```

(Generate all the individual BitSets from the map, then join them with reduce)

Comment: This also has quadratic performance. Why not `zip` with `l` instead of the index?

Comment: Ah, I didn't spot `l` was also a list, I thought it was a function call! Yes. Zipping with `l` makes more sense. Answer updated. Thanks

Comment: `(as, bs).zipped map f reduce (_ ++ _)`

Comment: Didn't know you can pass a tuple to a function expecting two arguments!

Answer (score 1):

You would say `foldLeft` is a better friend than `foreach`.

```scala
val l: List[Int] = ???

def shiftAndJoin(values: List[Int]) =
  values.zip(l). // 1. zip
    foldLeft(immutable.BitSet.empty) { (s, z) => // 2. recursion
    val (v, li) = z // tuple from join
    s ++ f(v, li) // create updated set
  }
```

1. Create a `List[(Int, Int)]` by zipping/joining current each value from given collection with corresponding one from `l`.
2. For each tuple from the join, create an immutable set, created by appending result of `f` to previous one.

As following it could be more efficient without first `zip` step, doing all while folding.

```
import immutable.BitSet

(values.foldLeft(0 -> BitSet.empty) { (st, v) => 
    val (i, s) = st
    (i+1) -> s ++ l.lift(i)./*get Option[Int] from l*/
      fold(BitSet.empty/*no new elements as nothing in l at index i*/)(f(v, _)/*new from f*/)

  })._2 // BitSet from last fold state
```

Comment: I think your second approach is worse performance-wise. `l.lift.apply(i)` is troubling. First if you want to use `lift`, lift once before the `fold`, so you don't create a new object every time. Secondly indexing is `O(n)` on `List`, so you will have a quadratic performance regarding `l`.